# javascript url validation help

Tags: php, javascript

If user enters a URL, as soon as they 
have completed the URL and hit enter the URL 
will appear below the text box and the text 
box will be emptied again.

It will only do this if it is a validly formed URL. For example if 
someone writes `blahbla.243`, this will not do 
anything as it is not a valid URL.

It will, however, accept any variations that are valid 
such as `http://www.url.com` or `www.url.co.uk` and
`url.com.au`.

And it will remove anything after 
the end of the country code for example if 
the person types `www.abc.net/dlkjfk` then 
only `www.abc.net` will be accepted.

Thank you!

Comment: __What is your question.__ I have a few ideas, but this isn't a thought exercise; it's a supposed question.

Comment: He needs the regex for a valid url (I guess).

Comment: Ok. And what have you tried so far? What do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be as strict as you're looking for, but it's what I use and its decent

```
var reg = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;

if(reg.test(elem[i].value) == false) {

//not cool story

}else{

//good link

}
```